# Is it possible to replace the content of a binary file in Alfresco? If not, is it possible to replace the entire file?

Tags: alfresco

Is it possible to replace the content of a binary file in Alfresco? 
If not, is it possible to replace the entire file?

thanks

Comment: How do you want to make the change? Java? JavaScript? CMIS? FTP? CIFS? WS*? Existing WebScript? New WebScript you're going to write (and if so what language)?

Answer (score 1):

The content is just a property on a node of type cm:content, so yes this is possible. In fact every time you edit the content of a file in Alfresco the content is replaced. Its just a matter of choosing what technique to use.

Comment: I am using Java. I was able to update the files with this code:

ContentWriter writer = getContentService().getWriter(node, ContentModel.PROP_CONTENT, true);
MimetypesFileTypeMap mimeTypesMap = new MimetypesFileTypeMap();
String mimeType = mimeTypesMap.getContentType(file);
writer.setMimetype(mimeType);
writer.putContent(file);

However, I found that this also changes the create date on the files. Is there a way
to update the file contents without changing the file's create date?

Answer (score 1):

It should help you:

```
ContentWriter writer = contentService.getWriter(nodeRef, ContentModel.PROP_CONTENT, true);

writer.putContent(inputStream);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess below is another approach.

```
ContentData content  = ContentData.createContentProperty("My content.");

nodeService.setProperty(nodeRef, ContentModel.PROP_CONTENT, content);
```